# How to get indices of drag and drop in PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

How do I get the index from where an `item` was dragged and index where it was dropped ?
I can get the `from index` using `currentRow()` in `dropEvent()` but Idk how to get the `drop index`.

```
class ListWidget(QListWidget):
    ...
    def dropEvent(self, event):
        fromIndex = self.currentRow()
        QListWidget.dropEvent(self, event)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event (QDropEvent) returns the position where the mouse is dropped and with that information the row is obtained:

```py
class ListWidget(QListWidget):
    def dropEvent(self, event):
        fromIndex = self.currentRow()
        toIndex = self.count()
        ix = self.indexAt(event.pos())
        if ix.isValid():
            toIndex = ix.row()
        print("from {} to {}".format(fromIndex, toIndex))
        QListWidget.dropEvent(self, event)
```

Comment: I guess the right index would be ```toIndex - 1``` ?

Comment: @scicyb That depends on "DropAction", that is, if you move or copy the item. And if you want the row before or after the drop. Since you do not provide an MRE I have considered a generic case and then you will have to particularize it. But it is rare that you want to know that row, maybe you have an XY problem.